# Adding languages in Windows Vista login screen

Tags: windows-vista, passwords, input-languages

A friend of mine is used a non-English password for his Vista laptop, and now he is in Vista login screen he has only English (I assume he removed the other language from the language bar by mistake and rebooted).

Is there a way to add a language or hack the OS without Vista installation CD (preferably also without Linux CD)?